# ML model for Signal Decomposition

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, factorization

So recently I got a task which can be summarized as follows:

Suppose we have 3 functions `f1, f2, f3` and a certain combination of the functions gives us `F`.

```
af1 + bf2 + cf3 = F
```

The component functions are simple and univariate. I have a range of values for their `x` and `y`.

In traditional regression, the task will be to approximate `F` while `f1...f3` are the inputs which vary on each datapoint and `a, b, c` are the weights we want to approximate and they will then be the same values used to compute `F` for all data points with unknown `F`.

In my case, however, the task is to learn the combination of `f1, f2, f3` that would yield a given `F` (or how `F` factorizes into `f1, f2, f3`). So `F` is known and `f1,f2,f3` are known too 
but the goal is to find the weights `a, b, c` which vary on data points.

I have researched how to frame this as an ML task and which paradigm to use but cannot find one yet. I have checked reverse regression, factorization machines, but none of these seems like what I need.

**UPDATE:** Some Context

I have 3 signals of intensity as a function of the wavelength of light used to generate the primary colours RGB. The functions to generate these signals are known. Now, these colours can be combined to obtain secondary colours whose signal is a linear combination of the RGB signals.

Hence, the task is: given the signal of a secondary colour, how do I determine the linear combination of RGB that gave that colour. Can a model be trained to learn the decomposition of the secondary colour signal into the RGB signals?

I hope this helps to better understand if my mathematical formulation above was not clear enough.

Any help on the direction to go will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I do not completely understand the problem you described, but it sound similar to "find functions `f1` and `f2`, such that together they give a known function `F = f1 + f2`". Essentially for arbitrary `a, b, f1, f2` and `c != 0` you can write a function `f3 = (F-af1-bf2)/c` that satisfies your original equation. Basically, your problem has one to one mapping from left to right (right hand side is unknown, left is known), but the right to left is one to many (infinite in fact).

Comment: @Aramakus You got a bit of the idea but I am not looking for `f1, f2, f3` as they are known and do not vary. Rather I am looking for `a, b, c` such that `F` factorizes (or decomposes) into `F = a*f1 + b*f2 + c*f3`. The solution does not have to be unique, Any values for `a, b, c` which satisfy the equation for a given `F` are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are looking into a fitting problem (least square fit for example). This is equivalent to a [Linear Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) with [MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) loss. Your variables are `a, b, c`. Your `Y_i = F(x_i)`, and your `X_i = ( f1(x_i, f2(x_i), f3(x_i) )`, where `x_i` is a set of discrete points of your choosing, the more the better, but you may want to start with about 20, and experiment by gradually increasing their number and see how your fit improves. Hope this helps. I assume you are familiar with `sklearn`, it has an excellent out of the box [Linear Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) module (note that MSE loss is hardcoded into it's definition). Here is an example of extracting optimized parameters:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Generate X and Y from the equation y = 1 * x_0 + 2 * x_1 + 3
X = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3]])
y = np.dot(X, np.array([1, 2])) + 3
# Fit Linear Regression model
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
# Get coefficients
print(reg.coef_)
```

will output `[1., 2.]`

Addressing your particular question. I assume that you do not use filters and just observe a total intensity in each pixel of your detector irrespective of the underlying wavelengths. Lets assume that `IR(x_i), IB(x_i), IG(x_i)` are known distributions of red, green, and blue signals. Lets denote `IM(x_i) = a*IR(x_i) + b*IB(x_i) + c*IG(x_i)` to be a mixed color. expressed as a linear combination of intensities from the red, green and blue sources (values of all those intensities are known as a function of pixel position `x_i`). If the goal is to work out `a, b, c`, then you can denote `Y_i = IM(x_i)` and `X_i = (IR(x_i) , IB(x_i) , IG(x_i))` and follow the linear regression code.

P.S. note that from fore the physical reasons, `a, b, c` are >= 0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Linear regression was the first thing I considered but it doesn't really fit. The goal is to output `a, b, c` given any `F(or Y_i)`. Using Linear regression as you just explained will help to estimate `Y_i` after training and getting estimates for `a,b,c`(only one set of values needed as opposed to my case where they vary). As you can see they are quite different.

Comment: Indeed, you can use it to predict `Y_i`, but since you interested in `a, b, c`, you can just train it and output these parameters when the procedure converges. I am updating the answer, as I cannot put the code here.

Comment: Exactly what I am saying. In this case, we get single values for `a, b, c` as a result. In my case `a, b, c` are variables which vary for each `X_i`.

Comment: So your functions vary with `x_i`, and your `f1, f2, f3` as well?

Comment: If it helps, the description of function decomposition here is close to what I need https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_decomposition

Comment: Sorry, I meant the big `X_i` according to your answer above. 
So the question is essentially, how do I decompose a given function `F` into smaller known functions `f1`, `f2` and `f3` given that it is a linear combination of these functions

Comment: Under signal processing section (of wiki article) the weights for functions are constants. Moreover, even in the general case, the first equation, it is just and abstract function of the basis functions `g_1 ,..., g_m`. I don't think I understand the mathematics of what you are actually looking for.

Comment: Yes, the description in the Signal Processing section doesn't fit my task. The first section `Basic mathematical definition` is closer to my task though the g1...g_m are not arbitrary but known functions

Comment: I will add more context to my question and hope it helps to understand it better

Comment: Please check my updated question with some context. Thank you

Comment: It just so happens that I am a physicist, working on X-ray optics though.

Comment: Oh nice. I am more of a Computer Scientist but I currently work in a Physics Lab. So my tasks are usually physics related. Nice to meet you!

Comment: Ok, thanks. For some reason, I've been fixated on the idea that the weights `a, b, c` have to vary which makes it impossible to use linear regression because we only obtain one set of weights. But maybe it doesn't have to be so. I will try this and see how it goes

Comment: Sure, no problem! Please accept the answer if this ends up working.

Comment: Sure. I will try it tomorrow and get back to you

Comment: So I tried this and for some reason, the results are very poor. But the more concerning issue is that due to the fact that the weights obtained (`a, b, c`) are constant, it then means that every secondary colour has the same mixture formula from RGB for a given wavelength. But this isn't so because they usually can be mixed in different proportions to get different colors

Comment: The sets of `a, b, c` should be unique for each mixed color. This means that you need to run this procedure for every mixed color separately.

Comment: There are millions of mixed colours so it is almost impossible to do that. In my dataset, each mixture and the constituent colours is a single datapoint. The goal is to find the proportion of the constituents of any mixed colour

Comment: I am sorry to hear that the answer to your question did not help you with your task. Unfortunately I cannot dedicate any more of my free time to your task as there are other people who also require help. Good luck!

Comment: It's Ok. Thanks for your help!